# Django object is not iterable. How to get most viewed object

Tags: django

Hi I am newbie and i am getting error "'Zagrania' object is not iterable". I want to get most viewed object and display it differently (wyswietlenia-views of object)

```
views.py

def zagrania(request):
zagrania = Zagrania.objects.all().order_by('-data')
najepszezagranie = Zagrania.objects.all().order_by('-wyswietlenia').first()

return render(request, 'zagrania/zagrania.html', { 'zagrania':zagrania, 'najepszezagranie':najepszezagranie})


models.py

class Zagrania(models.Model):
tytul = models.CharField(max_length=70)
data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
autor = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
opis = models.TextField(max_length=276, default='')
wyswietlenia = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
filmik = models.FileField(upload_to="static/filmiki")
#votes= models.IntegerField(default=0)







template

{% for zagranie in najepszezagranie %}

  <a href="{% url 'zagrania_detail' zagranie.id%}">

    <video>
    <source src="{{ zagranie.filmik.url }}" type="video/mp4"></source>
    </video>
  </a>

   <a href="{% url 'zagrania_detail' zagranie.id%}">{{ zagranie.tytul }}</a>


{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the `najepszezagranie` object is *not* a `QuerySet` (or any other collection) of `Zagrania` objects, it is a `Zagrania` object. So the `{% for zagranie in najepszezagranie %}` makes no sense.

You thus can use `najepszezagranie` as an object (well it is an object), and remove the `{% for ... %}` loop:

```
<!-- template.html -->
<a href="{% url 'zagrania_detail' najepszezagranie.id %}"><video>
    <source src="{{ najepszezagranie.filmik.url }}" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video></a>
<a href="{% url 'zagrania_detail' najepszezagranie.id %}">{{ najepszezagranie.tytul }}</a>
```